# How to show another button by clicking a button?

Tags: android

I don't want to create a new activity. Just like this gentleman's example (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6AdmCIe4Ik),but I want to implement this on LinearLayout using Button instead of main.

Say on the video at 00:44 user clicks a button specified on res/layout/activity1.xml and sub button shows up at 00:47.

He implemented it using menu and creating a sub folder (menu) under res instead of using layout.

What I would like to do is that once user clicks a button declared on LinearLayout it will show another button just like 00:47 on the video.

Answer (score 0):

With a very simple XML file:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button1" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button2"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in code, you set the listener for button1 as follows:

```
private Button button1;
private Button button2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
  button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);

  button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
  });
}
```

This code sample sets up the event listener for the first button and, when clicked, changes the visibility of the button from gone (which means it takes up no space in the layout and is invisible) to Visible, which is the normal state.

Comment: Yeah...this works but the transition is not as smooth. Also the 2nd button should be only seen after the 1st button is clicked.

Comment: Understood, that's why I set the visibility to 'gone' in XML.  As for smoothness of transition, that's easily enough accomplished by having the parent view animate layout changes.  Updating above to accomodate.

Comment: It's an xml attribute of ViewGroup (and thus linearlayout): android:animateLayoutChanges="true".  This tells the linear layout that whenever something occurs that will modify the layout (such as changing a view from View.GONE to View.Visible), animate that change to make it happen smoothly - it handles the animation for you. check  [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:animateLayoutChanges) out for more info.

Comment: This is a good example of layout transition animations: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/LayoutAnimations.html